# 1983 Mazda 323 won't start

Tags: starting, mazda, mazda-323f

I have a 1983 Mazda 323, and it won't start. The battery died from the radiator fan running over night, so I charged the battery all the way and it still won't start up. It sounds like it really wants to start, but it won't even bump start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you take the battery off to charge it? Does it 'chug' like it is occasionally firing, or can you just hear the starter running?